# Custom layout handle based on phtml file

Tags: layout, template, xml

I am trying to create a custom layout handle based on if the `page/popup.phtml` file is used as the template for the page.

I know how to build the module for the custom handle. The thing I don't know is the logic needed to find out if a page is using `popup.phtml` and if that is even possible since the layout files set a log of those templates.

**Update:** Here is the Observer code I am trying to use. It is failing on the line marked below (line 11) with this error:

> Call to undefined method
>   KNG_LayoutHandles_Model_Observer::getLayout().

```
<?php
class KNG_LayoutHandles_Model_Observer {
    /**
     * Adds layout handle modal_window.
     *
     * Event: controller_action_layout_load_before
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function addPopupHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $template = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate(); //Failing here

        /**
         * Return if it is not modal window
         */
        if ($template !== 'page/popup.phtml') {
            return;
        }

        /* @var $update Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update */
        $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $update->addHandle('modal_window');
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are loading that template through your own defined block, maybe you could just check if that block is loaded in the current layout, something like `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('your_block_name')`

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @benmarks I included javascript on all pages but now I need to remove it from all our popups.

Answer (score 3):

Once the layout is loaded (as it is for the `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` event) all of the actions have been processed. Adding a new handle to the update object at this point (or even manually merging its contents into the already-merged contents) doesn't make sense as you would have to regenerate things. You should take a different approach.

Stop and think what you need to do: unset JS on the **head** block, an instance of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`.

If you leave your current observer as it is configured, you can do

```
public function removePopupJs($observer)
{
    $list = $this->getRemoveList(); // not sure how you want to transport values in

    $root = $observer->getLayout()->getBlock('root');
    $head = $observer->getLayout()->getBlock('head');

    if (
            is_object($root)
            && $root->getTemplate() == 'page/popup.phtml'
            && is_object($head)
       )
    {
        foreach ($list as $type => $path) {
            $head->removeItem($type,$path);
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, not sure how you want to propagate "remove this, not that" into the observer context. It would suck to maintain dual lists in separate "spaces", i.e. one in layout XML for adding and one in PHP for removing. Perhaps, if all JS needing removal is added in one layout XML file, you could re-`load()` that file, or you could tag each JS-add directive with a custom attribute to select via XPATH.

You could also get rid of the observer and do the above in a helper method which just needs to be called after all JS has been added to the **head** block. Add your action to both the `<customer_logged_out />` and `<customer_logged_in />` handles as they will be executed on all page loads and after most other handles are executed.

There are other options as well. Layout it wicked flexible.

Answer (score 1):

The event you have chosen will not have any of the block information as it happens before all the layout is generated. My first suggestion is to use the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`.

This is dispatched as follows.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
    'controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after',
    array('action'=>$this, 'layout'=>$this->getLayout())
);
```

So you already have the layout passed into the event. You can then call the getBlock function on this layout object as follows.

```
$template = $observer->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate();
```

Comment: I tried your example code but i get this error: Call to a member function getTemplate() on a non-object

Comment: @Nick see my edited answer. But I am fairly sure that you could also do this via layout xml.

Comment: well you answer did make it so I could get the template inside the observer. The problem is that now the handle doesn't work because it tries to create it after the handles are already done. I may have to come up with another way to do this.

Comment: @Nick sadly I dont think this will work in your case as you need to load the blocks to get the templates but once that has happened you have already processed all the handles. As far as I am aware :(

Answer (score 0):

try this code this will help i think so.

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getTemplate();
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for but it doesn't work in the Observer class. I posted an update above with the error I am getting when using this. Any way to make it work in that class?

Comment: Your observer does not have a `getLayout()` method. But you can always use `Mage::app()->getLayout()`